# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android

```
private void showSignDialog() {
    dialog = new Dialog(Cust_My_Deliveries_Details.this);
    dialog.getWindow();
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //dialog.setContentView(R.layout.notification_dialog);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(Cust_My_Deliveries_Details.this);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.signature_bord, null);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayoutSign = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutSign);
    RelativeLayout Relative_clearSign = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.Relative_clearSign);
    RelativeLayout Relative_OkSign = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.Relative_OkSign);

    relativeLayoutSign.addView(signatureView);

    dialog.setContentView(view);
    dialog.show();
}
```

At first time the application displaying the dialog properly but while i am try to open it again ,my application crashing

Comment: Just move  `layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(Cust_My_Deliveries_Details.this);
    view = layoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.signature_bord, null);` in `onCreate(.....)`

Comment: I did, it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I think

> relativeLayoutSign

is already the Parent of

> signatureView

on the second call.

So you should write:

```
relativeLayoutSign.removeView();
relativeLayoutSign.addView(signatureView);
```

Comment: I removed the signatureView in next call but.again same issue comming

Comment: Maybe the Dialog has already a contentView, try the same there.